# app.config inside .ebextensions is not getting updated with `eb deploy`

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using `eb deploy` from the command line to deploy changes to my Elastic Beanstalk environment (a Flask app). However, when I make changes to my `app.config` file (which contains `container_commands`), and then run `eb deploy`, the post commit commands being run are from the old `app.config` file, and never seem to update.

When I examine the zip file actually submitted to AWS, it reflects my app.config changes.

Any ideas on what might be going wrong here? I have verified that I am pushing changes to my git branch before attempting `eb deploy`.

Thank you!